# Обработка события onclick и возвращение в исходную

Tags: jquery, события, javascript

Помогите решить задачу.

Нужна функция, которая при загрузке страницы будет искать `span` c классом `text` (он может быть не один) и если найдет будет выводить кнопку (прим.: `<a href='#' class='new'>add text</a>`) в начале тега `body`.
При нажатии на эту кнопку к тексту, уже имеющемуся внутри `span` c классом `text`, добавляется еще текст (прим.: `added text`) и кнопка, пример которой был выше, будет меняться на другу. (прим.: `<a href='#' class='old'>old text</a>`) при нажатии на которую текст будет приходить в исходное состояние

```
<body>
<span class="text">1 text</span><br />
<span class="text">2 text</span><br />
<span class="text">3 text</span>
<body>
```

Всё что у меня получилось, но не работает =(

```
$(function(){ 
if($("span").hasClass("text")){
$("body").prepend("<a href='#' class='new'>add text</a>");}
$("a.new").click(function() {

    var n = $(".text").html();
    $(".text").html(n + 'some text');
    $(".new").removeClass().addClass('old').html('old text');
});
});
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно таким образом сделать:

```
var mySpan = $('span.text');
var but = '<a href="#" class="new">Добавить текст</a>';
if(mySpan.length > 0){
    var cacheSpan = mySpan.map(function(i,el){
        return $(el).text();
    }).get();
    $(but).prependTo('body')
        .toggle(
            function(){
                $(this).text('Вернуть как было');
                mySpan.append(' <> added text');
            },
            function(){
                $(this).text('Добавить текст');
                mySpan.each(function(i){
                    $(this).text(cacheSpan[i]);
                });
            }
        );
}
```

[Смотреть пример тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/NVudJ/)

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо что-то такого плана?

```
 function test(){
    $('span').each(function(){
       var text =  $(this).attr('class');
       var num = $(this).attr('id');
       if(text == 'text'){
        $('body').prepend("<a href='#' class='new' id="+num+">add text</a><br>");
        }
    });
    $('a').click(function(){ 
          var num = $(this).attr('id') -1;        
          var info = $('span').eq(num).html();          
          var cl =  $(this).attr('class');
        if(cl == 'new'){
          $(this).removeClass().addClass('old').html('old text');
          $('span').eq(num).html(info + ' some text');
        }else{
         $(this).removeClass().addClass('new').html('add text');
            $('span').eq(num).html('add Class'); 
        }
       });

}
test();
```

[Вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/shanhaichik/3ZNSL/)
​